# favorite changes - removing favorites

Tags: discussion, behavior, favorites-notifications

Is anyone considering unfavoriting questions because of the "favorite changes notifications"? I really liked that the favorites was a list of questions I wanted to quickly access if needed but could essentially forget about...

On the other hand though, notifications to questions marked favorite because they are of current interest or changing etc is really neat...so I'm not against the favorite notifications at all...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/allow-users-to-opt-out-of-all-favorite-notifications/51955#51955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could accomplish the list of questions you want to quickly access with browser bookmarks, or at the very least a text file full of URLs. Alerting you when a question changes, on the other hand, would be somewhat more difficult to do externally, so it's nice that there's a one-click SOFU solution for it